# Rider suggests to use C# 8 syntax but then fails to build solution

Tags: c#, resharper, rider

Rider suggests to use C# 8 syntax, such as [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations) or [async streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams).

However, when I apply the recommended refactor, build fails on syntax errors.

My `csproj.DotSettings` file contains the language level set to `latest`:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">latest</s:String>
...
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

To clarify - I'm all for using C# 8. Where can I set the compiler target language? Or could it be just not supported yet?

In my project properties:

[image: props]

[image: props]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use C# 8, you need to install MSBuild 16 and then write the exact version of the language in the project settings (csproj).

```
</PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```